# addEventListener Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I don't know why but when I click on "button" nothing happens...

No message in console, no error. How to fix it ?

JS

```
var bird = (function(){

    let button    = document.querySelector('#addBird');

    button.addEventListener('click', addBird);

    function addBird()
    {
       console.log('addBird');
    };

    return {
        addBird: addBird
    };
})();
```

HTML

```
<button id="addBird">Add Bird</button>
```

Comment: If you run that JS *after* the button exists then [it works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/af95Lnrw/). Though it doesn't really make sense - why are you immediately binding `addBird` as an event handler but also returning it as a method of your object?

Comment: I just pasted your code into fiddle and it seems working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/o1mf1gxw/

Comment: @nnnnnn Because I tried using the console (via console it works). And Actually It works fine like this. I didn't give you all my code. And the issue is due to the _render() function which return Mustache.render(...). Please take a look : https://jsfiddle.net/458szLun/1/

Comment: Ok if I insert <input> and <button> outside the #birdMod It works... So it was not the .render() function. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if I insert  and  outside the #birdMod It works... So it was not the .render() function. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this example in CodePen:

http://codepen.io/JasonGraham/pen/pbowXz

```
var bird = (function(){

    let button    = document.querySelector('#addBird');
    button.addEventListener('click', addBird);

    function addBird()
    {
       console.log('addBird');
    };

    return {
        addBird: addBird
    };

})();
```

As far as I can see, your code appears to be working as expected. In Chrome, clicking on the button causes the "addBird" message to be logged to the console each time.

Are you expecting something different?

Comment: So your "answer" to "Why doesn't this work?" is "It does work"? That's more of a comment (and in any case doesn't require a repeat of all of the OP's JS).

Comment: If it isn't broke, don't try to fix it :).

Comment: The question states explicitly that there is "no message in the console" for the OP. So for them it isn't working as expected. Obviously they're doing something else wrong, because the code itself is fine (assuming the JS is run after the button is added to the DOM).

Comment: @nnnnnn, without proper mcve its just guesswork. He could redefine "console" for example, or make some unclear devtools tuning...

Comment: Yes, that's a fair point! I added OP's JS because it wouldn't let me embed a link to the working example without it. I'm new!

But I do disagree that it isn't worthwhile to let OP know their code is fine. They might have different expectations of what "working" is (Hence the question I pose in the edit).

Comment: Thank you for saving my life. <3

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the JavaScript loads before the DOM (basically, the HTML markup) is ready. Therefor, the `button` variable equals `NULL`.

Two ways to solve this:

- Move your JavaScript at the end of the page, just before the `</body>` tag.
- Wrap your JavaScript code with jQuery's document ready function:
  `$(function() {
      // code here
  });`

Comment: Nah, he have no errors in console. Try to load his script before dom and you will get "cannot read property addEventListener of null"

Comment: Actually every thing is OK. My problem is due to Mustache.render : https://jsfiddle.net/458szLun/1/

Comment: If I insert <input> and <button> outside the #birdMod It works... So it was not the .render() function. Thank you for your help.